# After Merge () of columns, lmer() ignores lines with NA value despite "all= True" - How to keep NA?

Tags: r, merge, na, lme4

```
I had the dataframe 'dat' with the columns 'subject_id' and 'boredom'. 
names(dat)
```

subject_id     boredom

There is a second dataframe 'fig2.int' with the columns 'subject_id', 'age' and 'gender'.

```
names(fig2.int)
```

subject_id     quality     age    gender

Both dataframes were merged:

```
dat2 <- merge(dat,fig2.int[c("subject_id","age","gender")],by="subject_id", all.x=T)

names(dat1)
```

subject_id    quality    boredom    age    gender

```
dat1$gender
```

1, 0, 1, 1, 0, NA
Then I did linear mixed models (LMM)

```
library(lme4)
```

Null model:

```
mod_zero <- lmer(quality ~ 1 + (1|subject_id), dat2)
summary(mod_zero)
```

Output:

```
Number of obs: 1037, groups:  subject_id, 119
```

Than I added successively variables starting with 'gender':

```
mod_one <- lmer(quality ~  gender + (1|subject_id), dat2)
summary(mod_one)
```

Output:

```
Number of obs: 1037, groups:  subject_id, 118
```

The number of groups is decreased from 119 to 118. When other variables were added, the number of groups did not change. The column 'gender' has one missing value (`NA`). Gender is just a control variable and I want to keep the participant. I read that `merge()` removes lines with NAs, but `all.x=T` or `all=T` should keep NA. This did not work. Has anybody an idea? I tired `aggregate()` but that did not work at all. Thank in advance, Andrea

Comment: `lmer` cannot include rows (i.e. observations or in your case respondents) that have missing values on any of the variables included. You'll have to deal with the missing data before running the model. Either exclude the case, exclude gender as a variable or look into imputation techniques.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! :-)